# Will a downvoted song on one Pandora station still play on other stations?

Tags: pandora

Sometimes I'm in a very specific mood and try to keep a variety of stations for that reason.  For instance I don't want Korn to play on a Hair Metal station.  But I still want those songs on the appropriate station.  Or I don't want journey playing on a station geared towards strictly Chick Rock.  But I want to keep listening to journey on their station.  You feel me?

Answer (score 1):

Accoridng to [this question on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Pandora-Radio/Are-Pandora-downvotes-global), downvotes are station specific.

Answer (score 1):

Thumbs-up/thumbs-down are station specific because otherwise if you downvoted a Katy Perry song on your Classic Rock station then it would affect your Katy Perry station too. You use the thumbs up/down system to individually craft each station to your preferences.